# Receive only one row, if multiple rows with same credentials exist in Django - SQLite

Tags: django, django-filter

I am looking for an elegant way to do a query in Django on a SQLite and only get one result, if there is multiple rows with the same content.

My example:

I have multiple time slots, which I model like this:

```
class Slots(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(_("Year"), blank=False)
    month = models.IntegerField(_("Month"), blank=False)
    day = models.IntegerField(_("Day"), blank=False)
    hour = models.IntegerField(_("Hour"), blank=False)
    block = models.IntegerField(_("Block"), blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(_("DateTimeField"), blank=False)
```

Lets assume I have two entries with:

```
 year = 2021
 month = 4
 day = 22
 hour = 15
 block = 0
 date = DateTimeField(2012/04/22,15:00:00)
```

And one:

```
 year = 2021
 month = 4
 day = 22
 hour = 16
 block = 0
 date = DateTimeField(2012/04/22,16:00:00)
```

When I do a:

```
 Slots.objects.filter(year=2021, month=4, day=22)
```

I get three entries, but I only want one for 15:00, as long as the condition is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [1] after query like Slots.objects.filter()[1]

Comment: This is only giving me the first row, I need to group by.

Comment: first you ask for only one result ("I get three entries, but I only want one for") now you want to group by . group by what exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Group By year, month, day, block

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django ORM's first() method (see [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#first)) as follows:

```py
slot = Slots.objects.filter(year=2021, month=4, day=22, hour=15, block=0).first()
if slot is None:
    # handle it
...
```

Comment: This is only giving me the first row. I need a grouping unfortunately.